# Plotting image on a surface in 3D [Matplotlib]

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm looking for a way to use matplotlib's 3D plotting
capabilities to display a flat image (a png or tiff) in 3D
space for some visualization I'd like to do.
The documentation is not very helpful,
is this even possible?

Comment: I would look at `mayavi`.

Comment: It is possible. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a post that shows how to do what you're looking for.

[Image overlay in 3d plot using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570287/image-overlay-in-3d-plot-using-python)