# Python: plot 3D shape over 2D image

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

I'm trying to plot a 3D shape with a 2D image overlaying the xy-plane. I've only just started working with python, so this is more challenging than it ought to be.

This question here addresses what I am trying to do : 
[Image overlay in 3d plot using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570287/image-overlay-in-3d-plot-using-python).
But when I run the provided code I get the following error:

```
File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
ax.plot_surface(x, y, 10, rstride=5, cstride=5, facecolors=img)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 663, in plot_surface
rows, cols = Z.shape
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

The image I am using is stored in the same folder as my 'test.py.' The question I referenced above uses an image from get_sample_data, but if I edit it to use my image, the code is as follows:

```
from pylab import *
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib._png import read_png

img = read_png('milkyway.png')

x, y = ogrid[0:img.shape[0], 0:img.shape[1]]
ax = gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, 10, rstride=5, cstride=5, facecolors=img)
show()
```

I get the same error whether I use get_sample_data or my own image.
Any suggestions of what I can change?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you upgrade your version of mpl?  That code works correctly with newer versions of the library.

Comment: I'm afraid not, I am doing this at work (university computers).

Comment: you can always install a local version of mpl.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be because plot_surface is expecting an array for the 'Z' argument, but you have given it the integer 10. (thus the error 'int' object has no attribute 'shape')

Comment: I want to put the image at z=0, so can I make z be an array of 0's? If so, and it needs to be the same size as x and y, can I write:
z = np.zeros(size(x))?

Comment: Have a look at the API documentation: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.Axes3D.plot_surface
Each argument is a 2D array providing the x, y, or z coordinate of a grid of points.

Comment: @user2569840 That is the right idea, but it should be `z = np.zeros(x.shape)`

Answer (score 0):

You're not loading your image correctly - `read_png()` need a file object as its input, not a file path. Try this:

```
 f = open('milkyway.png','r')
 img = read_png(f)
```

Comment: OK, what does `img` look like? Is it definitely a rows x cols x RGB(A) array? Can you just `imshow` it?

Comment: Yes, imshow displays it nicely. The trick now is getting it into a 3D plot.

Comment: Now `x` and `y` just need to be 2D arrays of the same shape as the image. In my version of matplotlib (1.2.1), `plot_surface` seems to accept an integer argument for `z`, but if that doesn't work you should also try handing it an array of the same shape as `x` and `y`: `z = np.zeros_like(x)`.